# Get directory of a symlinked script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, symlink

I have to determine the directory of a script which is symlinked.

```
/usr/local/src/myscript/myscript.sh
/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh (Symlink to the one above)
```

A cronjob executes /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh. Inside `myscript.sh` I am trying to determine where the original location is (which is `/usr/local/src/myscript/` in this case). How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is

```
$( cd "$( dirname "`readlink ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`" )" && pwd )
```

Comment: I'd even go for `readlink -f` to canonicalize even further.